# MySQL query help needed: Generate a report from the CUSTOMER table that displays the customer number (CUS_NUM)

Tags: mysql

Generate a report from the CUSTOMER table that displays the customer number (CUS_NUM), customer name (CUS_NAME), and the string "is *X* characters long" where *X* is the length of the customers name. (MySQL)

mysql> SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME, LENGTH(CUSTOMER_NAME)
    -> FROM CUSTOMER;

Comment: You just need to use the `LENGTH()` function to get the length of a string.

Comment: And use `CONCAT()` to concatenate strings to make a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

`SELECT CUS_NUM, CUS_NAME, CONCAT('is ',LENGTH(CUS_NAME), ' characters long') FROM CUSTOMER;`

Hope this helps,